# VS2012 can not add user defined control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have created my own control in VS2012 and later added that control to Windows Form. Everything was OK, until all the sudden this message started to pop up:

[image]

My control is no longer visible, it had just dissapeared. I've tried and create another component, but with the same result. Any idea what this is?

Comment: It seems like there is a file missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like it says: The file **Configuration.xml** is missing.

Comment: OK, it's missing. But what is this file? Why is it missing all the sudden?

Comment: I am not sure about this. Maybe you should ask google to get more information about that file and what it does. ;)

Comment: I have a file Configuration.xml in my project. I have copied manually that file to location C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE and the error went away. Why is this file needed there is still unknown to me. From the start, all was OK and this bug had pop uped all the sudden.

Comment: I'm not sure like I said, but maybe you find something about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx